# How do i search a string data (i.e. "12") from string array (i.e. ["12","13","1","2","30".....]) in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I am trying to search data from my mysql table. Table field type is text. My fields and data like:

[image: table data and fields]

When I am trying to query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `packages` WHERE `assign_div` LIKE "%1%" AND `assign_dist` LIKE "%1%";
```

it brings up all other data like "10", "51", "21" and so on (cos i have used "%%").

How can i arrange my query that only brings the passed data or
what will be the best way to convert those string array data and search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `"` to specify the accurate value

```
SELECT * FROM `packages` WHERE `assign_div` LIKE "%1%" AND `assign_dist` LIKE "%\"1\"%";
```